# Text view doesn't show after button click - Android

Tags: java, android, button, textview

I have a problem with Text View and Button in Android Studio. I would like to update my text view when i clik a button but it doesn't work.
This is my code:

activity_distance_to_run.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Distancerun2"
    android:layout_width="126dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="Distance to ....."
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/distancetorun"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="run"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/distancetoride"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/distancetoride"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/distancetoride"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="ride a bicycle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/distancetoswim"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/distancetorun"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Distancerun2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/distancetoswim"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="swim"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/distancetoride"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/distancetoride" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/yes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:text="I did it !!"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/no"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/no"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="116dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="I don't want to do it !!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="221dp"
    android:autoText="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:freezesText="false"
    android:text="Elo ziomek"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/no"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

distancetorun.java

```
package pl.agcode.sqliteexample;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class distance_to_run extends Activity {
Button distancetorun;
TextView txtView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_distance_to_run);
    distancetorun = (Button) findViewById(R.id.distancetorun);
    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    distancetorun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtView.setText("NewText");
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks for help I will try to repair it but don't know how.
This is very important to repair this for me. :)

Comment: Hi, please edit the question to indicate exactly what you expect to happen and exactly what is happening in practice, plus any error messages. 'It doesn't work' is not something the community here can help with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks all good except `textview1` color.

Add below line for the `textview1` in layout xml

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
```

After launching the app

[image]

After clicking RUN button

[image]

Comment: I changed color but it still doesn't work. Display custom text "Elo ziomek" but afer I click button textView does't change still show text "Elo ziomek" instead "New Text"

Comment: look at the updated answer. for me it does work. Make sure you are clicking on **RUN** button

Comment: @AGCode which button you pressing ?? I hope you are clicking on **RUN** button only

Comment: i changed for your code but still the same. Maybe button is locked or freezed or etc... i don't know :/

Comment: @AGCode try clean build, it should work. I have just copied your code, it does work

Comment: Is it possible the problem is according to virtual device in android studio ? But everything was good until this moment.

Comment: Thanks man I rebuilded my program structure and it works. Thanks so much for help.